# Adding a column to rails (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I’m trying to add a string column to a SQLite 3 database in rails. Use the normal syntax `"rails generate migration AddAuthorColumnToPublications author:string"`. I run the migration, it works without errors.

I change the attributes accessor in the Publications model to include the Author column. I check in the schema, the new column has been included in the schema.

I go to my database and the **new column does not appear** in the index of the Publications table. I’ve tried including it specifically in the index, but to no avail.

The only thing I can think of here is that because I am using Ubuntu, the syntax may be slightly different (as it has been for certain things).

I have looked in books and on the internet, and the syntax seems correct (can also use underscores as well as camel casing to name the migration), but I can’t find anything specific to Ubuntu on this particular issue.
I would appreciate any and all help on this matter.

Comment: Did you rake db:migrate ? Close the db and open it back ? And did you add the author field to the form you use for creating a publication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Migrations are not run automatically. You need to run `rake db:migrate` in order to run all the migrations and update the database.

Also, review your database.yml file and make sure that you're using the sqlite database that you're opening. The syntax of the command is not different.

Comment: OK.  I have closed and reopened the db, and I have added it to the form.  It comes up on the form, just not on the index.  I have been using rake db:migrate and its worked without incident .  I will check the yml file, cheers.  :-)

Comment: @PeterKenvin It needs to be added manually in the views. Open your `index.html.erb` and add a new column for this field.

Comment: alfonso, that was it mate.  Thankyou very much, problem solved (though Im looking and I dont know how to tag the post as solved - uber-newbie here)!  :-)

Comment: @PeterKenvin Awesome! Glad to help! You have to click on the empty check mark below the votes right next to this answer. The StackOverflow community appreciates it :)